# Magento2 addFieldToFilter call works with hardcoded value but not variable with same value

Tags: php, magento2

I'm building the admin for a Magento2 store (currently on 2.1.7, they want to use the newest version until we go live and then want to stabilize a particular version). The module in question is supposed to display all existing orders, with an actionsColumn that contains links to cancel, edit, and open a detailed overview of the purchased items associated with that order. The order detail page contains a grid view that should display all order items associated with an order number passed in the URL.

In order to filter out Order Items that don't relate to the specific Order Number, I've extended the `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult` class. This works except for one weird caveat. If, in the addFieldToFilter call, I replace $ordNum with, say, '10000', it grabs the correct data. When using $ordNum to call this dynamically, however, it returns no rows at all. This despite trying all sorts of casting and === checks to ensure that there's no difference between the hardcoded and dynamic values. Is this a Magento bug? I can't at all figure out why this would be the case.

```
<?php


class OrderItems extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult
{

    protected function _initSelect()
    {        
        $this->filterByOrderNum();

        parent::_initSelect();

        return $this;
    }

    private function filterByOrderNum()
    {
        $request = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                       ->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');

        $ordNum = $request->getParam('order_num');

        $this->addFieldToFilter('order_num', ['eq' => $ordNum]); //if I switch this to hardcoded 10000, this works. With the variable, no dice.

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: After the line - $ordNum = $request->getParam('order_num');  did you try breaking here and examining the value of $ordNum? Perhaps with: die($ordNum);

Comment: I did. As I mentioned above, even dumped a few "$ordNum === 10000" checks to ensure types were correct.

Comment: What if you replace this: $ordNum = $request->getParam('order_num'); with this: $ordNum = 10000;  See if you still get the same problem.

Comment: That works. I wonder if the getParam function is including some kind of markup then?

Comment: How is the order_num param getting passed? (I mean, what format is the complete result of the "get"?)

Comment: On the main order page, there's an actionsColumn that includes a link to the Order Item Detail page. That link connects to a custom "UrlBuilder" class that uses an instance of \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface to generate a URL formatted as {base_url}/orderitem/index/order_num/10000/

(Most of this I didn't build, still trying to learn my way around this codebase, hah)

Comment: Just saw the edit, unclear what you mean. getParam outputs a string 10000 (casting as an int doesn't solve the issue). getParams kicks out the same thing, just bundled as an array. $_GET comes up empty because Magento is very fun and lovely.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148546/discussion-between-tbowman-and-sitrick2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just fixed it by using mentioned below steps

Store param value in session in controller

```
public function execute() { 
  $this->_catalogSession->setTokenId($this->request->getParam('entity_id')); 
  $this->_view->loadLayout(); 
  $this->_view->loadLayoutUpdates(); 
  $this->_view->getPage()->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Redeem Token History')); 
  $this->_view->renderLayout(); 
}
```

Use session value in dataprovider

```
$tokensCollection->addFieldToFilter('token_id', ['eq' => $this->_catalogSession->getTokenId()]);
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this in place of the getParam statement:

```
$url = parse_url($request);
$path =  explode('/',$url['path']);
$ordNum = $path[3];
```

Just to make sure we are on the same page, this is the full code:

```
<?php


class OrderItems extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult
{

    protected function _initSelect()
    {        
        $this->filterByOrderNum();

        parent::_initSelect();

        return $this;
    }

    private function filterByOrderNum()
    {
        $request = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
                       ->get('Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http');

        $url = parse_url($request);
        $path =  explode('/',$url['path']);
        $ordNum = $path[3];

        $this->addFieldToFilter('order_num', $ordNum); //if I switch this to hardcoded 10000, this works. With the variable, no dice.

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Negative, still the same issue.

Comment: Can you add a break after this to check the values. Something like: die("order_num: " . $ordNum . " full url: " . $request);

Comment: Output of that:

order_num: 10000
    full url: GET {base_url}/orderitem/index/order_num/10000/key/{key hash}

There's header and cookie info too but nothing that looks particularly relevant.

Comment: Wait - it shows that $ordNum is 10000, but it's still not working? I thought you said it was working with the variable when the variable was actually set to the correct number?

Comment: I must've explained poorly, apologies. The variable is getting set to the correct value, but when it comes through the URL the addFieldToFilter function won't match it and return results, even though the value is correct.

Answer (score 0):

We have solved this issue by doing the following :

```
/**
 * CcCustompriceProductListingDataProvider constructor.
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $primaryFieldName
 * @param string $requestFieldName
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\ReportingInterface $reporting
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
 * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
 * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder $filterBuilder
 * @param array $meta
 * @param array $data
 * @throws \Exception
 */
public function __construct(
    $name,
    $primaryFieldName,
    $requestFieldName,
    ReportingInterface $reporting,
    SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
    RequestInterface $request,
    FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
    array $meta = [],
    array $data = []
) {
    $data['config']['filter_url_params']['product_id'] = $request->getParam('cppc_product_id', 0);
    parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $reporting, $searchCriteriaBuilder, $request, $filterBuilder, $meta, $data);
}
```

You do not need to use any other function. The reason why this is is because it is also updated with an update URL and that does not have that parameter. By using adding that to the data it also parses that into the update url.

You can see that here (Parent function)

```
/**
 * @return void
 */
protected function prepareUpdateUrl()
{
    if (!isset($this->data['config']['filter_url_params'])) {
        return;
    }
    foreach ($this->data['config']['filter_url_params'] as $paramName => $paramValue) {
        if ('*' == $paramValue) {
            $paramValue = $this->request->getParam($paramName);
        }
        if ($paramValue) {
            $this->data['config']['update_url'] = sprintf(
                '%s%s/%s/',
                $this->data['config']['update_url'],
                $paramName,
                $paramValue
            );
            $this->addFilter(
                $this->filterBuilder->setField($paramName)->setValue($paramValue)->setConditionType('eq')->create()
            );
        }
    }
}
```